# How can I allow insecure registries in Portainer?

Tags: portainer

I'm running a private container registry on my docker host. The same docker host is running Portainer and I would really like to keep using Portainer to manage my docker host.

But since I'm running a private container registry its only set up with http, and I need to configure the container client do allow http.

I've tried opening console on Portainer on the running Portainer container but It only "refreshes" the window.

I've puttyied in and tried to attach to the container but this only crashes the container.

Any clue on how to access the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` resource in the portainer instance?

Answer (score 2):

Portainer interacts with the host's docker daemon, so edit (or create) the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file on the host